2D Top-Down. World generation problems | Unity engine
I want to make a regular world generator with a chunk system, but I've been sitting for 3 days now and I don't understand why nothing works. I use 3 main scripts to generate the world: 'World.cs, Chunk.cs, ObjectPool.cs' I used to try to do generation based on pearl noise, but then I thought it was nonsense because I want the texture of the generated world to be a regular sprite, they say that the entire world the player will walk on is made of 1 sand sprite. Chunks seem to be generated and unloaded, but for some reason there is no world texture.
Chunk.cs: https://pastebin.com/AFgkHHke
World.cs: https://pastebin.com/tq2ZNm0Z
ObjectPool.cs: https://pastebin.com/VS28w1SV
Screenshot`s: https://imgur.com/a/FIToipu // I don't know why, but maybe they are needed

Please don't write that I'm an idiot. It's better to explain what the problem is than to cover me with dicks
I tried to post these pieces of ChatGPT code, but in 90% of cases it did not give any clear information or even gave me new scripts that did not work
